# Import data from spreadsheet into database without primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet file with 1500 rows, and this file is updated once day. All information in this file is to be stored in a table and there is no primary key in the spreadsheet file.

I have to read title of row one by one and then run query to find primary key and finally store data. Is not it better that primary key is same with title of data for that reduce 1500 query for finding primary key?

Comment: Why compare one by one and not use a `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you should put all rows of spreadsheet into staging table.

After you can do a `INNER/LEFT JOIN` with your final table.
Below an example of this:

```
—-for existing rows
SELECT S.*
FROM 
    dbo.STAGING S
    INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE T ON T.ID = S.TITLE

—-for new rows
 SELECT S.*
 FROM 
     dbo.STAGING S
     LEFT JOIN JOIN dbo.TABLE T ON T.ID = S.TITLE
 WHERE
     T.ID IS NULL
```